# AngularJS Plunker is not Working

Tags: angularjs, plunker

I Don't know why it is not working 
here is the   [`Plnkr`](https://plnkr.co/edit/WdOqUkOQZ0TARhrM1Dy9?p=preview)

but the same file is working here [`Plnkr`](http://embed.plnkr.co/OF044j)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is remove the http:/ part from the angular reference,

```
 <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.7" data-semver="1.2.7" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.7/angular.js"></script>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/2GUAvRYIU3hUsUntFjQT?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanx Man You are Great.